# What is the difference between acceptability,computability,decidability and recognizability in automata theory?

Tags: automata

When we say recursively enumerable languages are recognizable and recursive languages are acceptable by turning machine, what is the difference between these two terms? And also what is the meaning of TM Computable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A language is recursive iff there exists a total Turing machine that accepts it, which means that the Turing machine computation is finite on every input word over the same alphabet. The TM will always halt and will either accept or refuse the input word. 
Recursive == decidable. 
 
A language is recursively enumerable iff there exists a Turing machine that recognizes it. The property is weaker. The TM will accept a word that belongs to the language, but in case of a word not in the language, it can either refuse or loop. 
 
The set of recursive languages is a subset of recursively enumerable languages, therefore every recursive language is also recursively enumerable.

 
 A function f: N → N is computable if there exists a Turing machine that gets a number n in binary as an input and outputs f(n). The output is what is written on the tape after the computation. 

This is pure theory, it might be best to pick up lecture notes / a book in the future ;)